# Javascript Concatenation

Tags: javascript

I came across the following snippet of codes in a javascript quiz online. I could not understand how this concatenation works in JS. Can some one explain how this works ?

```
[] + [] = ""    // output : ""

[] + [] + "foo" // output : "foo"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript tries to apply the `+` operator in different ways, it's been taught to.

So unless explicitly told, it calls the **toString** method of the **Array** which is it's best guess when it's told to add two arrays.

```
[] + [] = ""

+[] + [] = "0"    // If you give a hint to cast one of the array to a Number

+[] + +[] = 0     // If you give a hint to cast both the arrays to Number
```

---

While `[] + [] + "foo"`  is simply

```
([] + []) + "foo" = "" + "foo" = "foo"
```

Comment: Can you also explain how does +[] gives 0

Comment: See it this way `-[]` gives `-0`. So the `+` here denotes the sign of a Number, hinting to the JS interpreter to cast the following item `[]` as a Number

Answer (score 2):

When you say `[]` + `[]`, JavaScript tries its best to convert the operands to numbers.

As per [Addition operator's ECMA 5.1 specification](http://es5.github.io/#x11.6.3),

> ```
> 4. Let lprim be ToPrimitive(lval).
>
> 5. Let rprim be ToPrimitive(rval).
> ```

So, first, they are tried to converted to primitive values with [`ToPrimitive`](http://es5.github.io/#x9.1). As Arrays are objects, JavaScript tries to retrieve the default values and use them as primitive values.

> Return a default value for the Object. The default value of an object is retrieved by calling the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of the object, passing the optional hint PreferredType. The behaviour of the [[DefaultValue]] internal method is defined by this specification for all native ECMAScript objects in 8.12.8.

When [`DefaultValue`](http://es5.github.io/#x8.12.8) is called without any hint, it will consider that as Number, by default.

> When the [[DefaultValue]] internal method of O is called with no hint, then it behaves as if the hint were Number, unless O is a Date object (see 15.9.6), in which case it behaves as if the hint were String.

And the default value is retrieved like this

> ```
> 1. Let valueOf be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "valueOf".
> 2. If IsCallable(valueOf) is true then,
>     a. Let val be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of valueOf, with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
>     b. If val is a primitive value, return val.
> 3. Let toString be the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of object O with argument "toString".
> 4. If IsCallable(toString) is true then,
>     a. Let str be the result of calling the [[Call]] internal method of toString, with O as the this value and an empty argument list.
>     b. If str is a primitive value, return str.
> 5. Throw a TypeError exception.
> ```

So, it tries to get the `valueOf` of the object and tries to execute that, which returns `[]` and that is not a primitive value. The [primitive value](http://es5.github.io/#primitive_value) is defined like this

> member of one of the types Undefined, Null, Boolean, Number, or String as defined in Clause 8.

Since neither of them can be converted to primitive values, they are converted to strings with `toString`. Since they are empty arrays, string values are also empty strings.

That is why

```
console.log([] + [] === "");
# true
```